# Direct print from React Native to Zebra ZQ520

Tags: android, react-native, expo, zebra-printers

I'm currently trying to print from my React Native app to a Zebra ZQ520 portable printer. I have been able to print using a 3rd party print service, but part of the problem is I also need this to direct print (silent print) as I want to avoid the Android print preview screen.

I'm using Expo for development so this adds another issue as a lot of the libraries cannot be used without first ejecting from Expo. This is something that I can do if need be, but right now I'm just trying to find the best solution to this problem.

So far I have printed through the 3rd party print service by calling Expo's `Print.printAsync(options)` and passing through HTML but again, this only serves to call the android print preview screen which I'm trying to avoid. I've also looked at PDF direct from Zebra (https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/printer-software/pdf-virtual-device.html) which shows some promise as you can also use Expo's `Print.printToFileAsync()` to save to .PDF format. With this option I just currently haven't found if it's possible to use PDF direct  from an Android device.

The thought I had with ejecting was using the react-native BLE PLX package (https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx) to handle the direct connection with the Zebra printer and send raw CPCL commands to the printer. The issue this seemed to raise was the limitations in terms of any images that may need to be printed.

I'm very new to React and up until now I've never had to work with hardware either so I'm trying to learn as I go. If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution a few months back and figured I should post the answer in case it helps someone else.  The library mentioned above by anderwald I had actually checked out at one point, but it wasn't robust enough for my needs as I needed to direct print a .PDF

I ended up dropping Expo and just converted my app to a pure react-native build and to handle the connection, I went with a service from these guys: https://mobiprintapp.com/

This wasn't 100% ideal, as there was a small licensing cost required, however it was easy to integrate and did exactly what I needed it to do, so for me it was worth it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I am probably on the same boat as you however I am using a ZT410 printer. I was able to do a simple HTTP Post with ZPL commands to the printer. Not sure if that's supported for your printer.

```js
  function Print() {
    var zpl = "^XA" + "^FO50,50" + "^A0N50,50" + "^FDHello, World!^FS" + "^XZ";
    fetch("http://192.168.0.58:6101/pstprntHTTP/1.1", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain",
        "Content-Length": zpl.length,
      },
      body: zpl,
    });
  }
```

Comment: Why "http://192.168.0.58:6101/pstprntHTTP/1.1" instead of http://192.168.0.58:6101/pstprnt ?

Comment: Thank you for your post, it works for my (ZT510)

Answer (score 1):

For anybody stumbling across this topic by now:
I managed to connect from an (ios) react native app to Zebra ZD421 via Bluetooth with this library: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-zebra-bluetooth-printer

You require the mac ID of the printer to connect, which you can figure out via the scan method of the library or the [Zebra Printer Setup Utility](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/zebra-printer-setup-utility/id1454308745).

After that you can basically print via the following command:

```
const printerSerial = String('87056752-6FCC-525A-4426-872756C3884A');
const zpl = generateZPL();
await RNZebraBluetoothPrinter.connectDevice(printerSerial)
  .then(async (res: any) => await RNZebraBluetoothPrinter.print(zpl))}
  .catch((err: any) => alert(`Problems while connecting to printer: ${err}`))
```

Comment: with zebra Printer Setup Utility, I only see the mac address, how do you find the uuid/ printerSerial for your printer? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## Silent Printing in React Native Expo App with Bluetooth Zebra Printer (No Permission Dialog!)

I recently tackled the challenge of silent printing from my React Native Expo app to a Zebra Bluetooth printer without opening a permission dialog, and I want to share the solution! This was a real headache for me, so I hope this helps someone else avoid the same struggles.

Solution:

The key to success was a combination of two things:

1. React Native Permissions: I used the react-native-permissions package to request and manage access to the Bluetooth printer.
2. react-native-bluetooth-zebra-printer-qv: This awesome custom library handles the actual printing communication with the Zebra printer. It's specifically designed for ZPL commands, which are the language used by Zebra printers.

It all come down to this:

```
import { RNZebraBluetoothPrinter } from "react-native-bluetooth-zebra-printer-qv";

const MAC_ADDRESS = "47:A2:53:CA:D5:D3";
const zpl = `^XA ^CI28
^FO50,50^A0,10^FDTesting print - font size 10^FS
^FO50,80^A0,20^FDFont 20^FS
^FO50,120^A0,30^FDתירבע 30^FS
^XZ
`;

async function printZpl() {
  console.log("Printing zpl");
  console.log(zpl);
  try {
    const res = await RNZebraBluetoothPrinter.print(MAC_ADDRESS, zpl);
    console.log(res);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    alert(error);
  }
}
```

Additional Resources:
check the conversation on the issue section here:
https://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-zebra-bluetooth-printer/issues/18#issuecomment-1857945293

I hope this helps! Feel free to ask any questions you might have. Happy printing!